# Extracting the first n elements from a Singly Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am trying to write a method that takes in an integer n and returns a new list containing the first n elements of its current object, List, in the same order in which they appear in the current list.

A solution that I have is provided below:

```
public List firstNelements(int n) {
    List newList = newList();
    Node travel = head, last = null, newNode;
    int counter = 0;
    while (counter < n && travel != null) {
        newNode = new Node();
        newNode.data = travel.data;

        if (last == null)
            last = newList.head = newNode;
        else last = last.next = newNode;

        counter++;
        travel = travel.next;
    }
    return newList;
}
```

I understand that the method begins by declaring a new list. From there, it declares the "travel" node, which is used to iterate throughout the current list. Also, I believe "last" is just there to keep track of the last node in the current object.

I also understand the first part of the while loop; however, I do not understand why the conditional

```
if (last == null)
            last = newList.head = newNode;
        else last = last.next = newNode;
```

is present. The node "last" is null when the code is first executed, so in the first iteration, I'm guessing that we are setting newNode to the head of the new list. But why are we updating last as well? Does this mean that "last" is keeping track of the last node in the new list? I also have no clue what the "else" statement is doing here.

I have traced through the list {1, 2, 3} with n = 2. However, I still cannot make much sense of it. The rest of the while loop (after this conditional) makes sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object you have to work with seems to be a linked list, i.e. each `node` is having a reference to the next `node` in the list. One node is special and is called `head`.  This allows to iterate over all elements from the beginning `head` to the end (when `.next` is `null`). During the first iteration this `head` must be set to have something in the list to iterate over later. When `last` is `null` the while loop is executing the first time. If this is not the first loop then just the `.next` pointer of the `last` node considered in the previous loop is set, to have a proper linking between the elements.

Is this a homework?  Maybe the Java [`LinkedList`](http://%20https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) is doing something similar internally. If this not a homework the better approach would be to use existing solutions from the Java Collection framework and e.g. the [`subList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList(int,%20int)) method.

Comment: Yes, it must be identical to individually setting `last = newNode` and `last.next = newNode`. Best is to attach a Java debugger to the program, available in all IDEs like Netbeans, Eclipse, IntelliJ community which will rapidly simplify the development.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (last == null) {
    last = newList.head = newNode;
} else {
    last = last.next = newNode;
}
```

- If last is null, set `newList.head` to `newNode` and then `last` to `newNode`.
- If last is not null, set `last.next` to `newNode` and then `last` to `newNode`.

Each iteration creates `newNode = new Node()` and assigns `newNode.data` to `travel.data`.

Let's say Iteration 1 creates Node1 and Iteration 2 creates Node2.

In the returned structure, Node1.next needs to be Node2.

When we're in Iteration 2, we've already processed Node1 without any knowledge of what was next (i.e. Node1.next is null). So -- how does Node1 know that "Node1.next" should be "Node2"?

That's what this conditional does.

Comment: "In the returned structure, Node1.next needs to be Node2.next" -- Shouldn't Node1.next be Node2, not Node2.next?

Comment: @stackofhay42 yes! Thank you - corrected. Also clarified the assignment order in the bullet point list.